# How to save a large file on external storage at Installation in Android?

Tags: android, installation

I am creating an Android App that uses the [MapsForge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge) library to show a map. The Map view in MapsForge shows data from a large file. Once this file is present, it will only be read, and never edited.

While developing, I am manually copying the file to the external storage.

How do I make the apk contain this file, and make sure that at the installation of the APP, this file will be written to the external storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the APK contains the file, and you write it to external storage, it will be both in the APK and on the external storage. You do not want that.

You want to either:

- Download the file via HTTP when the app is first run
- Use [APK expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)